# Plotly R: Add space in-between y-axis labels

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to add space/margin in-between each y-axis label, so the points do not overlap, but I have not been able to find a solution.

[image: Screenshot of the graph]

The code for generating the plot is here:

```
library(tidyverse)
devtools::install_github('danielludolf/FFplot')
library(FFplot)
library(plotly)

p <- data %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = `Race/Ethnicity`, y = fct_inorder(Measures))) + 
labs(x = "", y = "") +
geom_point(aes(size = Pixels,
             text = paste0(
               "Measure: ", str_wrap(Measures, 60), "<br>",
               "Disparity: ", str_wrap(`Race/Ethnicity`, 50), "<br>")),
         color = '#004c89', stroke = 1) + 
theme(legend.position = "none")

ff_ggplotly(p, source_name = "Add Source Here", width = 750, height = 550) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(gridcolor = '#d4d4d3'))
```

The dataset I am using is below:

```
structure(list(Measures = c("Zero Net Worth", "Zero Net Worth", 
"Uninsured", "Uninsured", "Unemployment", "Unemployment", "Poverty", 
"Poverty", "Median Employment Income", "Median Employment Income", 
"Liquid Asset Poverty", "Liquid Asset Poverty", "Income Insufficiency", 
"Income Insufficiency", "Housing Cost Burden (renters)", "Housing Cost Burden (renters)", 
"Housing Cost Burden (homeowners)", "Housing Cost Burden (homeowners)", 
"Houshold Underbanked Status", "Houshold Underbanked Status", 
"Household Banking Status", "Household Banking Status", "Homeownership", 
"Homeownership", "Employer-Provided Health Insurance", "Employer-Provided Health Insurance", 
"Educational Attainment", "Educational Attainment", "Business Value", 
"Business Value", "Asset Poverty", "Asset Poverty"), `Race/Ethnicity` = c("Black/AA, NH : 
White, NH", 
"Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", "Black/AA, NH : White, NH", "Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", 
"Black/AA, NH : White, NH", "Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", "Black/AA, NH : White, NH", 
"Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", "Black/AA, NH : White, NH", "Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", 
"Black/AA, NH : White, NH", "Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", "Black/AA, NH : White, NH", 
"Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", "Black/AA, NH : White, NH", "Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", 
"Black/AA, NH : White, NH", "Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", "Black/AA, NH : White, NH", 
"Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", "Black/AA, NH : White, NH", "Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", 
"Black/AA, NH : White, NH", "Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", "Black/AA, NH : White, NH", 
"Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", "Black/AA, NH : White, NH", "Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", 
"Black/AA, NH : White, NH", "Hispanic/Latino : White, NH", "Black/AA, NH : White, NH", 
"Hispanic/Latino : White, NH"), Pixels = c(35.4, 51.55, 91.4500000000001, 
79.1000000000001, 41.8517568812349, 19.0738225897106, 36.451355662209, 
84.5353032987158, 41.8689225795901, 52.8685324089523, 14.2245846952017, 
7.76867956641282, 13.775217283819, 9.77368755100193, 18.3689239165512, 
25.3197416180145, 11.9779708756455, 16.1033936963916, 34.8411564399252, 
22.7121030150228, 39.2441860465116, 28.75, 31.1957446808511, 
40.8170212765957, 75.4838709677419, 78.5483870967742, 32.075, 
42.8416666666667, 21.1139240506329, 26.0443037974683, 20.7666836410461, 
33.1868273779831)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `margin` in your `layout` function to create space between the y-axis labels. You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
devtools::install_github('danielludolf/FFplot')
library(FFplot)
library(plotly)

p <- data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = `Race/Ethnicity`, y = fct_inorder(Measures))) + 
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  geom_point(aes(size = Pixels,
                 text = paste0(
                   "Measure: ", str_wrap(Measures, 60), "<br>",
                   "Disparity: ", str_wrap(`Race/Ethnicity`, 50), "<br>")),
             color = '#004c89', stroke = 1) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")

ff_ggplotly(p, source_name = "Add Source Here", width = 750, height = 550) %>% 
  layout(margin = list(l=0, r=0, b=20, t=20, pad=0),
         yaxis = list(gridcolor = '#d4d4d3'))
```

Output:

[image]